# Get value of a specific rel using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, rel

I'm trying to get the value of a rel under "html > head > link". (link rel='shortlink').

I've tried this code (and some others) with no luck, it just says "undefined".

```
var shrt = jQuery("html > head > link").find('shortlink').attr('rel');

alert("short: " + shrt);
```

Anyone?

Comment: How about `$('link[rel=shortlink]')`? also why do you need `.attr('rel')` when you use `shortlink`in the selector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using attribute selector like below,

```
$('link[rel=shortlink]')
```

Comment: If I use: `var shrt = jQuery('link[rel=shortlink]');` it returns "[object Object]" in the alert?

Comment: Just the returned string. It's a Short URL. The entire thing looks like this in the source: `<link rel='shortlink' href='http://mydomain.com/prTY9' />`

Comment: @J.ScottElblein So you want the `href`? Try `$('link[rel=shortlink]').attr('href')`

Comment: That did it, thanks! Slowly learning my way around jQuery, lol.

Answer (score 1):

var findit = $('head').find('link[rel="shortlink"]');